# how to repeat alarm week day on in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I want to get alarm on monday to friday only.
my code is here

```
if (chk_weekday.isChecked()) {

                    int day = calNow.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
                    if (day == 2 || day == 3 || day == 4 || day == 5
                            || day == 6) {

                        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                                calSet.getTimeInMillis(), 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
                                pendingIntent);

                    }
```

Have a Idea.

Comment: Another approach: Create 5 alarms (one for each day) and set repeating time to WEEK.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

please try this code. is successfully run in my apps

```
if (chk_monday.isChecked()) {
                        forday(2);
                    } else if (chk_tuesday.isChecked()) {
                        forday(3);
                    } else if (chk_wednesday.isChecked()) {
                        forday(4);
                    } else if (chk_thursday.isChecked()) {
                        forday(5);
                    } else if (chk_friday.isChecked()) {
                        forday(6);
                    } else if (chk_sat.isChecked()) {
                        forday(7);
                    } else if (chk_sunday.isChecked()) {
                        forday(1);
                    }

public void forday(int week) {

        calSet.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, week);
        calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuts);
        calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calSet.getTimeInMillis(), 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
    }
```

Comment: it won't work if user want to set Alarm for more than one day.

Comment: its not complete but demo for @user1662296 some changing is depend of user.

Comment: i agree with @Lucifer this wont work if the user sets alarm for multiple day of week this will only work on singlechoiceitems

Comment: remove "if{}else if{}.."just use "if{} if{}..." then it should set alarm for multiple days....:)

Comment: Why do we set this to repeat every hour?

Comment: You are repeating it every hour. For every week formula would be 24 * 7 * 60 * 60 * 1000

Comment: why don't you add all of your check boxes to an arrayOf checkboxes and then using a for loop check for the checked ones and save their index to an other array and after that use an other for loop to set alarms for every number in that array

Answer (score 4):

From your question i believe you want to perform certain activity on daily basis except Saturday, Sunday. So your code is right but you declare it wrong way, make changes as follows and try

declare alarm in OnCreate() method

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(), 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000,  pendingIntent);
```

Now your alarm is set to repeat daily, and you need to perform action daily except Sat,Sunday

```
  if (chkMonday.isChecked()) 
  {
      activityToPerform();
  }

  if (chkTuesday.isChecked()) 
  {
      activityToPerform();
  }

  if (chkWednesday.isChecked()) 
  {
      activityToPerform();
  }

  if (chkThrusday.isChecked()) 
  {
      activityToPerform();
  }

  if (chkFriday.isChecked()) 
  {
      activityToPerform();
  }

  if (chkSaturday.isChecked()) 
  {
      activityToPerform();
  }

  if (chkSunday.isChecked()) 
  {
      activityToPerform();
  }

  private void activityToPerform()
  {
    // your action code
  }
```

Comment: can you give one example please

Comment: @user1662296, i have already coded for you, just study it and implement it your self.

Comment: thank you very much..but one more thing. i have 7 checkbox of week day,suppose i check 3 checkbox like monday,tuesday,friday  so get alert only 3 days. can you suggest me please

Comment: suggest you what ? ask your question briefly please.

Comment: suppose i have 7 check box like monday to sunday. i will check only 3 check box like monday , friday , sunday then get alarm play only those 3 day which is already check .alarm only play monday,friday, sunday .give any example

Comment: @ckpatel  how u implemented your scenerio can u pls share i also stuck here  
suppose i have 7 check box like monday to sunday. i will check only 3 check box like monday , friday , sunday then get alarm play only those 3 day which is already check .alarm only play monday,friday, sunday .give any example

Comment: You are repeating it every hour. For every week formula would be 24 * 7 * 60 * 60 * 1000

Answer (score 2):

One way is when the alarm notify is receive in broadcast then check the next day if its saturday then set the alarm for monday otherwise just create with adding 1 day.

You need to set new alarm every time for this.